# Why didn't I get the stats e-mail from Riot Games?

Tags: valorant

So Riot Games mailed the stats of every Valorant player today. But I got no mail.

What are the possible reasons for this? And is there any way to request my stats?

Or can I just check them in the game?

Comment: Might be because of delays. Let us wait and see.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this official tweet](https://twitter.com/PlayVALORANT/status/1413905858342313985), you need to have marketing emails turned on:

```
Miss out on the #yr1stats email? Round 2 is coming next week to everyone who's opted in:

Head to https://account.riotgames.com >> Communication Preferences >> Then check the "Communications from Riot Games" box.

After that, sit tight.  You'll see how you stack up soon.
```